# Is the <utility> header file present in versions prior to C++11?

Tags: c++, std

Previous versions of C++ defined `std::swap` in the `<algorithm>` header, but now it's been moved to `<utility>`. I'm pretty sure the latter header file existed in previous versions of the standard, but I'd really appreciate a confirmation on that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. It's where `std::pair` was formally included back in C++03 along with the `std::rel_ops` namespace that provided relational operators such as !=, >, >= and <=.

It's formally defined in section 20.2 of the C++98 standard.

Answer (score 2):

[Yup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_%28C%2B%2B%29). It used to define `relops` and `std::pair`, as well as a few other things (still does, but now it also includes `swap` and the like).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly when  appeared but it was avery long time ago. It defines Pair which I have used for at least ten years....